# Any ideas on how to make a youtube video play without the automatic fullscreen on facebook?

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube

For instance, if you go ahead and use this code:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7F8ik6iUzxs?autoplay=1&fs=0 frameborder=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

And load it up on an IPhone Safari, when you play it, it will automatically go fullscreen.

Any idea on stopping this from happening? I basically want the video to keep playing without automatically enter fullscreen so the rest of the screen is still visible while the video is playing.

Ideally it will also autoplay.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a responsive div for it:

```
<div class="video-container"> <iframe width="100%" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7F8ik6iUzxs?autoplay=1&fs=0 frameborder=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"></iframe> </div>
```

The CSS:

```
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 35px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="video_frame"><iframe width="100%" height="480" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7F8ik6iUzxs?autoplay=1&fs=0 
frameborder=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"> . 
</iframe></div>
```

css:

```
.video_frame{
    width: 50%;
 }
```

Here is a media query for mobile if you need it.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){


    .video_frame {
    width: 100%;
    }
}
```